# Set status value with group by on different values with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT SUM(reach) AS reach, SUM(impressions) AS impressions, cpc, id_name,
       SUM(clicks) AS clicks, SUM(amount_spent) AS amount, pagename, status
FROM mbk_ad_data
WHERE id_campaign_shortname = 'name'
  AND adset_name NOT LIKE '%MSN%'
  AND date_from = '2016-02-02'
  AND date_to = '2016-02-09'
GROUP BY id_name
```

That will group and output this:

```
reach impressions cpc      id_name clicks amount pagename status
4099  4529        6.34875  name    29    246.11  Name     paused
```

This works almost as intended. I have two different rows with "pagename" Name and the summed up values are correct, but row 1 has status "active" and row 2 has status "paused". What I want is to have a status "active" in the output, if one of the rows has a status "active", so my output will be:

```
reach impressions cpc      id_name clicks amount pagename status
4099  4529        6.34875  name    29    246.11  Name     active
```

How can do this in the query?

Comment: I'd try and modify to a standard compliant `GROUP BY`, i.e. `GROUP BY cpc, id_name, pagename, status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `MIN` on `status`:

```
SELECT SUM(reach) AS reach, SUM(impressions) AS impressions, cpc, id_name,
       SUM(clicks) AS clicks, SUM(amount_spent) AS amount, pagename, 
       MIN(status) AS status
FROM mbk_ad_data
WHERE id_campaign_shortname = 'name'
      AND adset_name NOT LIKE '%MSN%'
      AND date_from = '2016-02-02'
      AND date_to = '2016-02-09'
GROUP BY id_name
```

This way `status = 'active'` will take precedence over `status = 'paused'`. This will work as long as the group contains just these two values for `status` field.

Answer (score 0):

You should get into the habit of including *all* non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.

Then, the rest can be done using aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(reach) AS reach, SUM(impressions) AS impressions, cpc, id_name, 
       SUM(clicks) AS clicks, SUM(amount_spent) AS amount, pagename,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(status = 'active') > 0 THEN 'active'
             ELSE MAX(status)
        END) as status
FROM mbk_ad_data
WHERE id_campaign_shortname = 'name' AND adset_name NOT LIKE '%MSN%' AND
      date_from = '2016-02-02' AND date_to = '2016-02-09'
GROUP BY id_name, cpc, id_name, pagename;
```

Although there might be a very slight performance hit for including all the columns, including all the columns more than makes up for that problem by (1) being standard SQL and (2) by preventing unintentional errors.